# Is this possible to fix this requirement (explain briefly in this question)?

Tags: graphics, numbering, external-files, write

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
blah blah blah blah blah blah

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{...eps}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-4]

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{...eps}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My requirement is, I need to extract the figure number with its corresponding output page number also with its file name to an external Word/Excel file, e.g.,

```
Figure 1              Page 1             test.eps
```

Is it possible either in `LaTeX` or through any external possibilities? Please advise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this should do it:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newwrite\imgdetail
\immediate\openout\imgdetail\jobname.imd

\let\LTXincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
  \write\imgdetail{\figurename\space\thefigure, Page \thepage, #2}%
  \LTXincludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
blah blah blah blah blah blah

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-4]

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

We allocate a write stream with `\newwrite\imgdetail` and open a file named `\jobname.imd` with `\immediate\openout\imgdetail\jobname.imd`.

Assuming you want to record all occurrences of `\includegraphics` (which, bear in mind, may or may not appear in a `figure` environment), we save the definition of `\includegraphics` in `\LTXincludegraphics` and redefine it to write the information to the `.imd` file:

```
\let\LTXincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
  \write\imgdetail{\figurename\space\thefigure, Page \thepage, #2}%
  \LTXincludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
}
```

this results, with the MWE, in a file containing:

```
Figure 1, Page 1, example-image-a
Figure 2, Page 2, example-image-b
```

Depending on your use case you might want to do this exclusively for figures inside a `figure` environment, then you might do something like this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
  \def\@tempa{figure}%
  \ifx\@currenvir\@tempa
    \write\imgdetail{\figurename\space\thefigure, Page \thepage, #2}%
  \fi
  \LTXincludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
}
\makeatother
```

still it wouldn't work if, for instance, you used in a `subfigure` environment.

Comment: Thanks, you understood the requirement exactly, and you are so great; very much pleaused with your solution and with very quick short time... thanks a lot...